# Question mark in URL is removed with Express Route Parameters. How can I get a post by title with a question mark? (Node.js/Express/MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, url

I tried to find and retrieve a post by a title but it failed and when I console log `requestedTitle = req.params.postTitle` it shows the ? is removed from http://localhost:1035/posts/Is%20Google%20Analytics%20is%20illegal? to just "Is Google Analytics is illegal" which fails to find the article with the title "Is Google Analytics is illegal?" with a ?.

```
  app.get('/posts/:postTitle', function (req, res) {
      //single blog post
      // const postId = req.params.postId
      const requestedTitle = req.params.postTitle
      Post.findOne({title: requestedTitle}, function (err, post) {
        console.log(requestedTitle);
        if (post) {res.render('post', {
          singleTitle: post.title,
          singleContent: post.content,
          singleAuthor: post.author,
          uploadedImg: post.img,
          postCreated: post.created_at
      })} else {
        res.send(`No "${requestedTitle}" article was found.`)
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A question mark is interpreted by Express (and per the http spec) as the delimiter for the URL query string.  As such, Express has already parsed out the query string and does not match that against your route.  The parsed query string will be in `req.query`.

So, if you send a request for a URL such as:

```
http://localhost:1035/posts/Is%20Google%20Analytics%20is%20illegal?
```

Then, the `?` will be seen as the delimiter for the query string and your postTitle will just be `Is Google Analytics is illegal`.

If you want a question mark to be part of what you get in `postTitle`, then the client will have to properly encode the `postTitle` using `encodeURIComponent()` before constructing the URL.  That would "hide" the `?` from Express (it would be encoded as `%3F` and it would then be left in the decoded value of `postTitle` as a `?`.

FYI, there are many other characters which are also reserved so ANY end-user content you're trying to put into the URL piece that you want to be `postTitle` MUST be encoded with `encodeURIComponent()` when constructing the URL.  Note, you don't call `encodeURIComponent()` on the entire URL, just on the piece of user data that becomes the postTitle.  Express will then handle the decoding for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had encodeURIComponent() the "requestedTitle" and it didn't work. However, encoding the "post.title" in ejs template worked. Thanks again

Comment: @basixnetflix - Yes, the URL that client sends to the server has to use `encodeURIComponent()` on that piece of the URL.  Depending upon how you construct that URL (which your question does not show), you would have to use `encodeURIComponent()` when building the HTML page or in the client-side Javascript that builds the URL.  Anyway, glad you got it figured out.